# Why do companies such as facebook share pretrained models for commercial use?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm curious about the motivation behind such a generous approach, I've used XLM-Roberta recently and I was impressed by its capabilities. That got me thinking, smaller companies wouldn't be able to train such models themselves, isn't it counterintuitive to allow them to use that tool?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the license for XLM-R is: **Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International**

See:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/XLM/blob/main/LICENSE

I won't claim to be an expert in CC licensing, but I interpret this to mean that you cannot use XLM for commercial purposes, whether that is providing access to the original pre-trained model (XML-R) or adapted/derivative works (your own models derived from XML-R).

Comment: very interesting!